# BQ E5 Ubuntu Edition: How to switch to another open source OS (e.g. Lineage OS)

Tags: ubuntu-touch, phone

I'm a little stuck! Ubuntu Touch is more or less abandoned and wasn't that good in the first place, TBH. So I'd like to flash my BQ E5 Ubuntu Edition with another open source OS.

Can anybody link me to a guide who to flash the phone with a new OS? I've googled the issue, found a guide on the LineageOS site for a similar phone (E5 4G), but I didn't get it to work...

Comment: E5 4G is not similar enough to support the same OS images as these images also include drivers for telephony etc. You can install Android on the E5 by following this guide http://a25.co/ubuntu-phone-how-to-install-android/ and the images provided on the official bq site for your phone. I have not done this myself yet (I own an E4.5). Of course this is only as opensource/Free software as Android is (much less than I would like).

Comment: Thank you for your reply! It's unfortunate news though...'regular' Android has proprietary code built into the OS and the version fitting for this phone is out of date, AFAIK.

So selling the phone and getting a S3 or something is the best option?

Comment: I don't know. Maybe there are cyanogenmod versions for it. I am still using Ubuntu phone...and will never sell it. Its going to keep my old Nokia N900 company, which had the most promising Linux implementation on a phone ever, but was killed by Microsoft. I hope this https://plasma-mobile.org/ becomes a product some day.

Comment: Wow, that would be nice!

Comment: I hope that the Ubuntu phone lives on in the future as it was showing great promise. I will continue to use my tablet abdicate keep the phone as it is now.  I personally think that Ubuntu should of sorted out the basics first on their oscar and then built on a solid base.

Comment: The Plasma mobile looks smooth in places, somethibg that Touch was missing in places.

Comment: @Bruni I feel like you could make an answer from your comments...

Comment: @Zanna The question has been put on hold as off-topic (though I think it is rather on the edge), so this is no longer possible, but thank you.

Comment: https://puri.sm/shop/librem-5/ It seems plasma mobile has a good chance of becoming a product after all.

Answer (score 2):

You can use "Ubuntu Touch" from the UBports-community, then you will get
critical security-updates and bug-fixes to your phone.
https://devices.ubports.com/#/vegetahd